# Error copying file from local to aws ec2 using scp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, file-transfer, scp

I am trying to copy local files to my ec2 instance.

When I run this command:

```
scp -i keypair.pem process.py ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/.
```

I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
lost connection
```

When I run this code:

```
scp -i keypair.pem process.py ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx:~/.
```

It stalls for ~ 1 minute then I get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx port 22: Operation timed out
lost connection
```

Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: In your second example, the command you give is `ec2-` (public DNS), but the error shows you really used `ip-`, which is the private DNS

Comment: I've been trying both as I've seen them recommended in multiple places. I don't really understand the difference, they behave the same in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use `scp` is to start with an SSH command that already works:

```
ssh -i keypair.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4
```

Then, modify it to use `scp`:

```
scp -i keypair.pem foo.txt ec2-user@1.2.3.4:/tmp/
```

The only things changed were:

- `ssh` becomes `scp`
- Insert source filename
- Append `:/target/`